# Ignoring an entire directory and subdirectories on CVS commit

Tags: maven-2, cvs

How does one ignore the entire contents of the a directory with name target in using a .cvsignore file.  I currently use eclipse IDE

I have tried to use target but it does not seem to work.  Should i rather be using target/* or target*.  This would be very important especially for Maven projects.

Answer (score 1):

Use just 'target' in the .cvsignore file